# Parse.com - .NET SDK C# LINQ join syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join, parse-platform

I'm attempting to implement the custom identity provider found at this link in an MVC 5 project: https://github.com/corrego/Parse.AspNet.Identity 
In part, it defines an IdentityUserLogin class, which is derived from ParseObject and has a ParseClassName of "UserLogin".

Now this code is tested and working, based on a UserLoginInfo object (loginInfo) passed into the method:

```
var queryLogin = from login in IdentityUserLogin.Query
                 where login.ProviderKey == loginInfo.ProviderKey && login.LoginProvider == loginInfo.LoginProvider
                 select login;

var userLogin = await queryLogin.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

As expected, userLogin gives me a populated IdentityUserLogin object. Now I want to extend this to bring back the ParseUser object associated with the UserLogin, which is referenced using a column of type 'pointer', name 'user' from UserLogin. For performance, I'd rather not use 2 separate calls, and the SDK documentation seems to indicate that it's possible to use a LINQ join, but I can't get it past the compile stage. This is what I have:

```
// Gives the following compilation error: 
// Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it 
// is not a delegate type   

var queryUser = from user in ParseUser.Query
                select user;

// See compilation errors #2/#3 referenced below.
var queryLogin = from login in IdentityUserLogin.Query
                 join user in queryUser on login.User equals user
                 where login.ProviderKey == loginInfo.ProviderKey && login.LoginProvider == loginInfo.LoginProvider
                 select login;

var userLogin = await queryLogin.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**Error #2:** 
The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'Parse.ParseQueryExtensions.Join(Parse.ParseQuery, Parse.ParseQuery, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'Parse.ParseObject'.

**Error #3:**
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Parse.ParseQuery'.  'Where' not found.

For reference, IdentityUserLogin.ParseQuery is defined as:

```
public static ParseQuery<IdentityUserLogin> Query
{
    get { return new ParseQuery<IdentityUserLogin>(); }
}
```

The correct syntax / approach to this would be highly appreciated!